# How to change the install path for PIP

Tags: python, pip

I got my *pip* install directory in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Somehow, after I install the wordbatch library, my *pip* install path changes to

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Does anyone know how to change the *pip* install path?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is you can just install it anywere. Then move it to the correct directory. This should fix the problem, if you want it to install there from the start. Then i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can see help of pip install in bash like pip install --help.
Current task you need use parameters --target /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.